# Possible alternate proof: a fact about Sylow $p$-subgroups and elements that have order a power of $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here's the Lemma that appears in my text:

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$. Let $x$ have as its order a power of $p$. If $xPx^{-1} = P$, then $x \in P$.

I seem to have come up with a simpler proof than the standard one but I can't spot the error.

Define $N = \{ y \in G \;: \; |y| = p^k \mbox{ for some $k$ and } yPy^{-1} = P\}.$ It's easy to see that $P \subset N$. It's also easy to see that $N$ is a $p$-subgroup, since every element has order equal to a prime power. Since $P$ must be maximal, we can conclude that $P = N$. Thus $x \in N = P$.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748005/let-k-be-a-sylow-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-g-prove-that-if-x-in-nk-an?rq=1) is about an identical question and has a more elementary answer but the top answer still invokes quotient groups.

Comment: How do you know that $N$ is a subgroup?

Comment: Ah. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: It almost makes it! But you're right, it's not at all obvious that that the product of two elements in $N$ also have order of a power of $p$. Thank you.